# Get Distinct records from MongoDB using lithium

Tags: mongodb, find, distinct, lithium

I want to find distinct records from a collected "pages".

I tried:

```
$Volume_numbers = Pages::find(array('fields'=>'DISTINCT volume_number'));
```

I also tried:

```
  $params = array('conditions'=>array(
        'distinct' => 'pages',
        'key' => 'volume_number',
        ));
    $pageVolumes = Pages::all($params);
```

as suggested in MongoDB documentation and also in one of the answers.

When I try to execute this through Mongo, I get correct results

```
> db.runCommand({distinct:'pages',key:'volume_number'})
 {
    "values" : [
            22,
            38
    ],
    "stats" : {
            "n" : 1084,
            "nscanned" : 1084,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1084,
            "timems" : 25,
            "cursor" : "BasicCursor"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This code worked for me!

`$pageVolumes = Pages::connection()->connection->command(array(
     'distinct' => 'pages',
     'key' => 'volume_number',
 ));  
`
Results:

 `Array
    (
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 38
        )

    [stats] => Array
        (
            [n] => 1084
            [nscanned] => 1084
            [nscannedObjects] => 1084
            [timems] => 3
            [cursor] => BasicCursor
        )

    [ok] => 1
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a wrapper method in `lithium\data\source\MongoDb` for the `distinct` command; however, the [MongoDb](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/source/MongoDb.php) class does compose the PHP driver's [Mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php) and [MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) classes, so you can do the following:

```
// Where $mongodb is an instance of lithium\data\source\MongoDb
$result = $mongodb->connection->command(array(
    'distinct' => 'pages',
    'key' => 'volume_number',
));
```

Alternatively, I'm sure Nate Abele would welcome a pull request to Lithium to add support for `distinct` to the `read()` method, just as it already has for `group` (in fact, the current code makes a good starting point to implement this).

Comment: I added:
    use lithium\data\source\MongoDb;
and 
    $result = $mongodb->connection->command(array(
      'distinct' => 'pages',
      'key' => 'volume_number',
    ));
To the code.. no results.

Comment: If there were no results, then `$mongodb` wasn't the same database resource used for the Pages model in your application. Based on your comment above, it looks like `Pages::connection()` returned the reference you needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me!

```
$pageVolumes = Pages::connection()->connection->command(array(
    'distinct' => 'pages',
    'key' => 'volume_number',
));
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 38
        )

    [stats] => Array
        (
            [n] => 1084
            [nscanned] => 1084
            [nscannedObjects] => 1084
            [timems] => 3
            [cursor] => BasicCursor
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```